# git confusing graph. `master` branch seems to have two lines?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-log, git-history-graph

On running `git log` i am seeing strange graph. I will explain it further.
Below is the output for git log with graph.

```
$ git log --graph  --oneline
*   df1834d (HEAD -> master, tag: r-0.1, origin/master) Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/samshers/graphql-hibernate
|\
| * d56a675 fixed country null issue
* | ee9bb70 fixed country null issue
|/
* 2617f2a hibernate cascade error issue. country field in state table set to null
```

As you an see master has two separate branches in itself. To confirm this further, i ran

```
$ git branch --contains ee9bb706c8fcc329fac4acf69ad6b684f1069170
  joincolumn_issue
  ls
  mappedBy
* master
```

And then

```
$ git branch --contains d56a6751771b1f62d9ceb0bcce9a2391c004ee44
  joincolumn_issue
  ls
  mappedBy
* master
```

**So clearly these two commits are present on master - so then why are there two graphs.** 
How can i know if **changes** both the commits are present on master. Or if only **changes** from one of them is actually present on the master, which one of the two?

**Edit - following responses from RY and Mark**
[image: adding the graph screenshot]   ( if color codes add any further meaning, please hint on that as well.)
So, am further trying to understand why a commit (Y) is not based on previous commit (X) ( if X was committed before Y). 
The git log shows that both `d56a675` and `ee9bb70`  where committed at the same time.

```
commit ee9bb706c8fcc329fac4acf69ad6b684f1069170
Author: itsvamshers <itsvamshers@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 9 17:24:01 2019 +0530

    fixed country null issue

commit d56a6751771b1f62d9ceb0bcce9a2391c004ee44
Author: itsvamshers <itsvamshers@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 9 17:24:01 2019 +0530

    fixed country null issue
```

But, on digging further the little difference can be seen..

```
$ git show -s --format="%ct" d56a6751771b1f62d9ceb0bcce9a2391c004ee44
1568030041
```

and

```
$  git show -s --format="%ct"  ee9bb706c8fcc329fac4acf69ad6b684f1069170
1568031643
```

and this info should be enough for git to put the commits in right order. But if it is not, then I guess it is smarter and doing it for reason, just trying to understand the reason and the cause.

Comment: actually both :) You see two commits because the __are__ different (maybe just the commiter or the date) as they have different sha1. the merge may have been without conflicts, but nevertheless, there are 2 discticts commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d56a675 isn’t present in the history of ee9bb70, and ee9bb70 isn’t present in the history of d56a675. Both are present in the history of master, because they were merged back together in df1834d. All of this is why the graph has a fork in it.

Both of their changes *exist* in the history of master, but that doesn’t mean the merge commit preserved those changes the way you might want. You have to look at the current state and compare.

```
git show d56a675
git show ee9bb70
git diff 2617f2a..df1834d
```

Also, if both commits are the same or if one is a newer version of the other (which their summary suggests), merging them is probably a mistake.

Comment: @samshers: Who authored the merge commit?

Comment: it was done by me... but working on the application logic I paid little attention to git stuff :-) so bad.  I am not able to understand, in general, how can there be a commit on a branch but that commit still be out of line with parent commit on the same branch.

Comment: @samshers: The left/right positioning isn’t significant there, only the connections. Neither of those commits is more “in line” with the parent commit than the other.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. But in future I don't want to run in to this issue, so am trying to find the root cause for this strange graph. If you can hint me on how to avoid this sort of situation in future or what cause this issue...  :-)

Comment: @samshers: Is there another branch or repository involved? Did this happen after pulling? Have you ever rewritten a commit? Was this commit part of a pull request?

Comment: added few more details on the question. no. none of those are the case. No other branch or repo. rewritting a commit if that same as amend, then don't think that's the case either. And pull request either.

Comment: @samshers: A GitHub remote counts as another repo – your local is another. Sorry I didn’t notice that the first time around. Do you work on the same project from different devices?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199488/discussion-between-samshers-and-ry).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the confusion is about what a branch is, and what it means for a branch to "contain" a commit in git.

A branch is just a pointer to a commit.  A branch is *not* a collection of commits in git, like it may be in some tools.  The closest thing git has to a branch "containing or not containing" a commit is, a commit either is or is not "reachable" by that branch.  The commit the branch points to is reachable, as is any commit found by following a reachable commit's parent pointers (recursively).

A merge is a commit with two (or more) parent pointers.  So when you merge a branch into `master`, all of that branch's commits become reachable from `master` (via the merge commit's second parent pointer).  So the branch commits are "contained in" master (i.e. reachable from master) because you merged them into master; this is normal git behavior.

If you want to know only the commits that were "on master" when committed... well, git doesn't *really* keep track of things like that, but you can do

```
git log --graph --one-line --first-parent
```

Now, if you do unusual things (like merging master into a branch and then fast-forwarding master onto the resulting merge, as just one example) then this still may not do quite what you intend; but if you follow a reasonably normal branch/merge strategy (and stick to "porcelain" commands - those intended for end-user use), it should look more like what you're expecting.

This behavior of `log` by default following both branches that came into a merge is the main reason the `--graph` option is useful IMO.

Regardless, the changes from all commits shown in your example graph are present in master, because they're all shown as reachable from master.  There is a gotcha - this assumes that the merge commit is a reasonable merge of the two branches.  If you merged with the `ours` merge strategy, then the branch is not present.  If you did something really weird with conflict resolution that undid some changes from a branch, then you have what is sometimes called an "evil merge" and the change it undid is not present.  If you know nobody on your team does such things, then you don't need to worry about that.

You can rely on `git log`'s history simplification to tell you if a branch was completely clobbered in a merge (such a branch should not be shown unless you give options like `--full-history`, because `log` will decide that it can fully explain the current state without mentioning the branch), but this may not be 100% reliable and in any case nothing in `log`'s logic can tell you if you have an evil merge - so at some point, you have to rely on the idea that you and your team follow reasonable processes.

Or good tooling and test coverage; you also could rely on that.

Comment: added more info to the question. I am now clear with the point you are making - that changes of both commits are reachable/present on master. Well, what I am wondering now is how come there can be two branch for a branch itself (like here the branch is master). Clearly `d56a675` is committed before `ee9bb7`, so why is not `ee9bb7` based on `d56a675`. why the fork.

Comment: @samshers - git doesn't decide which commits are based on which commits; that is decided by the user(s) as commits are created.  git *can't* just change it to be linear (though you can tell git to make a linear history using `rebase` commands).  Without knowing how/by whom the commits were created, I can't say exactly why they are the way they are - but generally it is because they were each created with the same "previous commit' checked out - not one created with the other commit checked out.

Comment: On re-reading your answer again - `A merge is a commit with two (or more) parent pointers.` - wondering when can this be true: a merge having more than two parents. Could you please explain - i am very interested in knowing this situation. Also if you can point to any github etc codebase which has this more than two parents commit, it will be even gr8.